# HTML5 Canvas increment x,y to origin(0,0) smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, vector, html5-canvas

Im trying to achieve a gravity like simulation where all points created on the canvas will return back to the origin(0,0)/or center of canvas from random generated spots on the canvas. Like stars sucked into black hole. How can i increment or decrement the x and y values so as they reach the destination at the same point? Now im adding or subtracting 1 (i also tried to decrement the bigger number slower) but im getting the x and y off so that it looks like the point hits a wall then drops or rises to the singularity.

Example:

```
var point = {
  x: 615,
  y: 215,
  radius: 2
 }

var singularity = {
  x: 751,
  y: 401,
  radius: 2    
}
```

Comment: whats your frames per second?

Comment: setInterval(this.draw, 1000/60);

Comment: You need to calculate the slope of a line between your current point and the origin and then adjust the coordinates each time you redraw so that the point is still on (or close to) the line.

Comment: You need to use physics and simulate acceleration. Basically create a `dx` and `dy` for the change in `x` and `y`. They apply a force vector towards `0,0` on each update by setting the values of `dx` and `dy`.

Comment: There's 0 gravity in space so it won't be necessary for this problem , instead you can increment the velocity variable to increase speed as suction occurs...

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/53goom8s/ (click in canvas to add point)

Comment: @KpTheConstructor There isn't 0 gravity in space, it exist everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I wrote for simple vector operations:

```
function vector(x, y) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    var point = this;
    this.toString = function toString() {
        return point.x + "," + point.y;
    }
    this.add = function (pos) {
        var x = point.x + pos.x;
        var y = point.y + pos.y;
        return new vector(x, y);
    }
    this.subtract = function (pos) {
        var x = point.x - pos.x;
        var y = point.y - pos.y;
        return new vector(x, y);
    }
    this.multiply = function multiply(scalar) {
        var x = point.x * scalar;
        var y = point.y * scalar;
        return new vector(x, y);
    }
    this.magnitude = function magnitude() {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.x, 2) + Math.pow(point.y, 2));
    }
    this.unit = function unit() {
        var mag = point.magnitude();
        if (mag === 0)
            return point;
        return point.multiply(1 / mag);
    }
    this.angle = function angle() {
        return Math.atan2(y, x);
    }

}
```

You can use this to calculate the distance, direction and angle to the singularity;

```
var itemPosition = new vector(point.x, pointy);
var singularityPosition = new vector(singularity.x, singularity.y);
var displacementVector = singularityPosition.subtract(itemPosition);

var distanceFromSingluarity = displacementVector.magnitude();
var directionToSingularity = displacementVector.unit();
```

There might be some typos in there but it should get you started.
Use the directionToSingularity.multiply(myCurrentSpeed) method in the vector object. It will give you a number you can add() to your pointVector to determine it's new location.

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the distance of the object from the center point:

`distance = sqrt((y1-y0)^2 + (x1-x0)^2)`

in your case `y0` and `x0 = 0` so `distance = sqrt((y1)^2 + (x1)^2)`

Then you have to figure out the proportion of `x` change and `y` change for that distance, so let's say the distance from origin for object A is 100 and it's coordinates are `(x, y)` then we know that, at each time interval, the `x` position needs to be incremented `((x-0)/100)*velocity` and `y` needs to be incremented by `((y-0)/100)*velocity`, *if we want the object to follow a straight line.*

You should add a velocity property to each object that gets its absolute value increased as you approach the black hole:

```
    var point = {
      x: 615,
      x0: 615,
      y: 215,
      y0: 215,
      radius: 2,
      velocity: -5, /* maybe make the initial value of this a function of intitialDistance to mimick black hole gravitational pull */
      intitialDistance: Math.sqrt(Math.Pow(this.x0,2) + Math.pow(this.y0,2)),
      deltaX: this.x0/this.initialDistance,
      deltaY: this.y0/this.initialDistance
     }

    var move = setInterval(function() {

      point.x += point.velocity * point.deltaX;
      point.y += point.velocity * point.deltaY;
      point.velocity -= 4;
}, 40);
```